# Is it possible to write chained comparison macro in Rust?

Tags: rust, macros

In rust, it's possible to pass `>` or `<=` etc inside macro arguments so long as the arguments are `ident`s.

Is it possible to create a macro that lets you chain comparison operators?

```rust
let x = 3;
let y = 1;
let z = -3;

assert_eq!(cond!(z <= x > y), true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to use `tt` for the operator type:

```
macro_rules! cond {
    (@rec ($head:expr) $last:ident $op:tt $next:ident $($tail:tt)*) => {
        cond!(@rec (($head) && ($last $op $next)) $next $($tail)*)
    };
    (@rec ($head:expr) $last:ident) => { $head };
    ($first:ident $op:tt $next:ident $($tail:tt)*) => {
        cond!(@rec ($first $op $next) $next $($tail)*)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 1;
    let z = -3;
    println!("(z <= x > y) = {}", cond!(z <= x > y));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63bc50288700819fcd04cc5a59a0e2d2)

You can also read [The little book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/) for more advanced macros patterns.

Comment: This does allow some odd constructs that might be problematic, like `cond!(x+y)`. But it sure is short and neat.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is technically possible, but I'm not sure I'd do it personally.
to handle all the operators without matching on some things that shouldn't work like `cond!(a + b)`, `cond!(a)` or `cond!()` I had to be pretty verbose, and use a recursive macro. It might be possible to simplify the initial (non `@recur`) cases, but I was worried that doing it wrong would lead to infinite recursion.

```
macro_rules! cond {
    ( @recur $x:ident ) => { true };
    ( @recur $x:ident < $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x < $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( @recur $x:ident > $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x > $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( @recur $x:ident <= $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x <= $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( @recur $x:ident >= $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x >= $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( @recur $x:ident == $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x == $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( $x:ident < $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x < $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( $x:ident > $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x > $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( $x:ident <= $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x <= $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( $x:ident >= $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x >= $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
    ( $x:ident == $y:ident $($tail:tt)* ) => { ($x == $y) && cond!( @recur $y $($tail)*) };
}

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 1;
    let z = -3;
    println!("(z <= x > y) = {}", cond!(z <= x > y));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could modify your example for supporting variable comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following does what you expect *as long as you are careful with the arguments to `cond`*.

It uses `tt` (for argument `operator0`) to match `<`, `<=`, `>=`, etc. to avoid repeating lots of cases, but `tt`, of course, matches other tokens, too.

```
macro_rules! cond{
    ($x:ident $operator0:tt $x0:ident) => {
        ($x $operator0 $x0)
    };
    ($x:ident $operator0:tt $x0:ident $($operator1:tt $x1:ident)*) => {
        ($x $operator0 $x0) && cond!($x0 $($operator1 $x1)*)
    };
}

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 1;
    let z = -3;

    assert_eq!(cond!(z <= x > y), true);
}
```